# Handling multiple applications from a single domain in Nginx

Tags: nginx

Im trying to configure Nginx to handle multiple applications (backends) to work off a single domain (`server_name`) and I'm running into a weird problem.

What I'm trying to do is,

```
www.test.com -------------> serving the main application (127.0.0.1:7888)
             |
             -------------> management application (127.0.0.1:2666)
```

The initial configuration I have is as follows,

```
server {
  listen  443 ssl;
  listen  [::]:443 ssl;

  server_name  test.com;

  ## SSL settings
  ssl on;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7888;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }

  location /management {
    rewrite ^/management/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:2666;
  }
}
```

This works well for the main application. It can also route to the `/management` application however it is trying to access `management` static files via the main application and it throws `404`.

To rectify this I modified the configuration as,

```
server {
  listen  443 ssl;
  listen  [::]:443 ssl;

  server_name  test.com;

  ## SSL settings
  ssl on;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7888;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
  }

  location /management {
    rewrite ^/management/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:2666;
  }

  location @fallback {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:2666;
  }
}
```

Now `/management` app works well but not the main application due to the `try_files` config.

Is there anyway to fix this issue ?

Comment: You need to fix your management app so that the URIs for its assets do not overlap the URIs for your main application. Alternatively, is there a unique pattern to the URIs which can determine which assets belong to which application?

Comment: That is a little bit challenging when the apps backend URIs are not configurable.